# How can I make DOM-less application with Elm0.18

Tags: elm

I need to migrate my nodejs application written in Elm0.17 which uses `worker()` method
for application initialization.
My app runs inside nodejs runtime (not in browser).

I migrated everything else and it compiles fine now with Elm0.18.
But no way of initializing it...

Can somebody help me find out how I can do the same with Elm0.18?

Comment: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Platform#program

Comment: Thank you!! Did not realize this part of API has changed so much...

Answer (score 0):

As @robertjlooby pointed out,
Elm0.18 has elm-lang/core which provides `Platform.program` that supports `worker()` initialization.